# This code is not running properly

Tags: c++

I tried to run the following code but after one input, the rest of the input is initialized to zero and is displayed on the screen automatically. where did I go wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#define N 50
using namespace std;

struct movies_t
{
    char title[60];
    int year;
}user[N];

void printmovie(movies_t);

int main()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter title: ";
        cin.get(user[i].title, 60);
        cout << "Enter year: ";
        cin >> user[i].year;
   }

   cout << "\nYou have entered these movie: \n";
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printmovie(user[i]);
   return 0;
}

void printmovie(movies_t m)
{
     cout << m.title;
     cout << " (" << m.year << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: this is c++ and not c =)

Comment: edited tags to not be c

Comment: it has to do with you not clearing out the newline from your cin.. but i don't remember how to fix it..something like cin.flush() or something.

Comment: `cin` does  not have a `flush()` method.  `cin.get()`, as you are using it, stops when it encounters a `'\n'` and leaves that `'\n'` in the stream, which will cause `cin >> user[i].year` to return immediately.    The real solution is not to mix usage of `cin.get()` (character input) with `>>`.   The solution which doesn't really work is to try to discard the newline.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you press enter after inputting the year for the first movie, that enter (newline) is still in the input buffer, so when you next call `cin.get(...)` it will read that newline and think you entered an empty line.

You need to tell `cin` to [*ignore*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of the line including the newline.

Answer (score 1):

After execution of

```
cin >> user[i].year;
```

the newline character is still left in the input stream.

The next time you execute

```
cin.get(user[i].title, 60);
```

the first character encountered is the newline character. When that happens, `failbit` of `cin` is set. Here's some info from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get (emphasis mine):

> 4) Reads characters and stores them into the successive locations of the character array whose first element is pointed to by `s`. Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:
>
> - n-1 characters have been stored
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (`setstate(eofbit)` is called)
> - the next available input character c equals `delim`, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. This character is not extracted (unlike `basic_istream::getline()`)
>
> **If no characters were extracted, calls `setstate(failbit)`**. In any case, if `count>0`, a null character (`CharT()` is stored in the next successive location of the array.

After the `failbit` of `cin` is set, nothing is read from `cin` until the state is cleared by an explicit call to `cin.clear()`.

Since you don't have any code to check the state of `cin` and clear the state when appropriate, nothing is read in the loop after the first iteration.

One way to fix the problem is add a line to ignore the contents of the stream after the year is read.

```
cin >> user[i].year;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Also, it is a good practice to *always* check the state of a stream after an IO operation to make sure that you don't overlook any errors.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   cout << "Enter title: ";
   cin.get(user[i].title, 60);
   if ( !cin )
   {
      cout << "Error reading title.\n";
      exit(1);
   }

   cout << "Enter year: ";
   cin >> user[i].year;
   if ( !cin )
   {
      cout << "Error reading name.\n";
      exit(1);
   }

   // Ignore everything up to and including the newline character.
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```